# Cannot use jQuery append with onsenui CSS and Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am trying to create an app using PhoneGap. I want to make a list view of lots of news. I came across this problem when trying to making a new piece of data in the list. Currently when I use the tags provided in an online example in my HTML, it works fine. I then try to insert the tags using jQuery, and they don't work properly.

Here is a screenshot showing you what's going wrong:
http://cl.ly/image/1k063m2y3V3B

The first two pieces of data are just normal HTML and then the last piece of data was inserted with jQuery. I am inserting the same code so it might be Angular and jQuery clashing that's the problem.

Relevant HTML:

```
<ons-list style='margin: -1px 0' id="data">

 <ons-list-item modifier='chevron' class='item' ng-click='doSomething()'> <ons-row>

<ons-col width='60px'> </ons-col> <ons-col> <header> <span class='item-title'>Rorem Ipsum</span> <span class='item-label'>5h</span> </header> <p class='item-desc'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> </ons-col> </ons-row> </ons-list-item>

 <ons-list-item modifier='chevron' class='item' ng-click='doSomething()'> <ons-row> <ons-col width='60px'> </ons-col> <ons-col> <header> <span class='item-title'>Rorem Ipsum</span> <span class='item-label'>5h</span> </header> <p class='item-desc'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> </ons-col> </ons-row> </ons-list-item>

</ons-list> </ons-page> </ons-navigator> </ons-template>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
$("#data").append("<ons-list-item modifier='chevron' class='item' ng-click='doSomething()'> <ons-row> <ons-col width='60px'> </ons-col> <ons-col> <header> <span class='item-title'>Rorem Ipsum</span> <span class='item-label'>5h</span> </header> <p class='item-desc'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> </ons-col> </ons-row> </ons-list-item>");
});
```

Comment: I cannot see any html that has the id "data". Have you tried hitting a breakpoint in the jQuery and typing $("#data") into the console to verify that this is populated with an element from your page?

Comment: Yes, sorry its not in the provided html, let me fix that.

Comment: @JDTLH9 `<ons-list style='margin: -1px 0' id="data">`

Comment: You should probably ditch the jQuery and use angular to bind your model to the DOM. Look at the built-in ng-model and ng-repeat directives. Is there any reason you couldn't do it that way rather than using document.ready in jQuery?

Comment: @JDTLH9 never learned Angular, so I am not really confident with it. if you use ng-repeat, can you change the data?

Comment: Okay. Yes where you have the ng-click directive that fires the "doSomething" function you can also add arrays and/or properties to the $scope object too. If you then use ng- model for properties and ng- repeat for arrays in your markup then any subsequent changes to this data in your JavaScript will update the DOM. It is worth looking into. AngularJS is a fanatastic framework and your JS code will end up being a lot more readable and testable than jQuery code. I hope this helps. I cannot see a quick win with the current code unfortunately.

Comment: Do ons.compile(element) and it should work. You need to compile all HTML that you dynamically add.